# OAuth 2.0 - Should Client Identifier be unique for each user or only by client type?

Tags: oauth, oauth2

**Oauth 2 Specification, Section 2.2. (Client Identifier) states** -

> The authorization server issues the registered client a client
>      identifier -- a unique string representing the registration
>      information provided by the client. The client identifier is not a
>      secret; it is exposed to the resource owner and MUST NOT be used
>      alone for client authentication. The client identifier is unique to
>      the authorization server.

My question is whether the `Client ID` should be unique for each end user or only by client type?

For example if I have a native app client, should each app install get it's own `client ID` or should all apps get the same `client ID`?

And is it the same for the `client_secret`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your native app client should use one client ID. In fact for most services you will get only one ID for your registered client (app).

It seems like you have some problems with the terminology in OAuth 2.0 (client, resource owner, resource, authorization), so maybe read a tutorial e.g. [this short one](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/client-types.html) to get a grasp for it.